# Webservice WinRT IOException: registry key does not exist

Tags: web-services, windows-runtime, ioexception

It's a very strange thing... We have a common cross platform base which contains a web service client (SOAP). On all platforms it's working very well but on WinRT we get the following:

> IOException: The specified registry key does not exist.

After checking the queries on the registry I've found out, the program tries to access a Clsid which does really not exist (with procmon).

There is no StackTrace and HResult is 2.

I really don't know what I could do to find out more about this error.

Someone else encountered problems like this?

Comment: Is your application one app running in dektop environment and you are trying to migrate to Modern UI?

Comment: no. I'm using a base wich compiles as Win Store Class Library. The base is based on a Silverlight library project, which was ported to iOS and Android. Therefore we didn't copy the files. We only did the linking to the in the new "Core"-projects.